# What is the difference between library and package?

Tags: matplotlib, package

I am little bit confused with the name package. I have heard about matplotlib plotting library for Python, gnuplotfortran plotting library for Fortran. But Can't I say them packages instead of library?

Please clarify if there is any difference between library and package in a broad sense.

Comment: Often (but not always) "package" refers to how the library is delivered.  For example, is it source code or a binary? A .deb, an .rpm, a .exe, a .dmg?  Of course, the terms "library" and "package" can be used interchangeably in some contexts, but it's fairly common to differentiate "a library" and "its packaging". In other words, the software vs. the delivery mechanism.  (Note that "packaging" essentially always refers to the delivery mechanism, while "package" is sometimes used in a broader sense, as you noticed.)

Answer (score 1):

Libraries are a more abstract concept than for example, packages, assemblies, or gems. The latter constructs are platform specific terms for concrete components of code bases. Libraries are often comprised of several components.

Think 
of libraries as sets of cohesive, related tools dealing with some problem domain. On the other hand, think of packages as units of organization and modularization for grouping code assets.